# Working with Fulcrum data in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have been sent some shapefiles, gathered using the Fulcrum app. However, when I load them into my project on QGIS 2.2, they wont display. They will display if I go to 'Zoom to Layer Extent" but under no other circumstances - even if I remove all other layers in the project.

Comment: First I don't know what this Fulcrum app is or does. It might help if you provide some information. Does the shapefile have information about projection, coordinate system? What is the projection, coordinate system of your project?

Comment: Feels like a somehow corrupted shapefile. I would try if making a new copy with ogr2ogr could correct it `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile`new.shp fulcrum.shp.